# Cannot mount glusterfs volume on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, glusterfs

I have deployed a GlusterFS cluster on GCE, three nodes, one volume and one brick. I need to mount it on a pod deployed on GKE. I have successfully created the endpoint and PV, but I cannot create the PVC, If I introduce the volumeName refered to my PV, I get the following error:

`2s          Warning   VolumeMismatch       persistentvolumeclaim/my-glusterfs-pvc    Cannot bind to requested volume "my-glusterfs-pv": storageClassName does not match`

If I don't introduce a volumeName selector I get the following error:

`3s          Warning   ProvisioningFailed   persistentvolumeclaim/my-glusterfs-pvc    Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": invalid AccessModes [ReadWriteMany]: only AccessModes [ReadWriteOnce ReadOnlyMany] are supported`

I though that glusterfs has native support on GKE, however I cannot find on the GCP site:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#storage_driver_support

Is it related to the errors I'm getting while deploying the PVC? How could I solve it?

Thanks!

I have not defined any storageClass. I can only find Heketi provisioned GlusterFS storageClass on Kubernetes documentation. My YAMLs:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-glusterfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  glusterfs:
    path: mypath
    endpoints: my-glusterfs-cluster
    readOnly: false
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-glusterfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  volumeName: my-glusterfs-pv
```

I have deployed Heketi on my glusterfs cluster and it works correctly. However I cannot deploy the pvc on GKE. Glusterfs-client is running ok, the heketi secret is available, the gluster storageclass has been created without errors, but the PVC remains in Pending an I have found this event:

```
17m         Warning   ProvisioningFailed       persistentvolumeclaim/liferay-glusterfs-pvc   Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gluster-heketi-external": failed to create volume: failed to create volume: see kube-controller-manager.log for details
```

Storageclass:

```
kind: StorageClass
#apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gluster-heketi-external
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
parameters:
  restauthenabled: "true"
  resturl: "http://my-heketi-node-ip:8080"
  clusterid: "idididididididididid"
  restuser: "myadminuser"
  secretName: "heketi-secret"
  secretNamespace: "my-app"
  volumetype: "replicate:3"
```

PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: gluster-heketi-external
 # finalizers:
 # - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: my-app-pvc
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

I also have created the firewall rule needed for Heketi, in order GKE nodes can access to Heketi resturl and port. I have checked that it´s working ok launching a telnet to 8080 port while I am sniffing the traffic on the Heketi node. Everything appears to be ok, I can see the answer and the packets. However I cannot see any packet when I deploy the pvc. There is nothing on syslog. I can create volumes when the heketi command is launched locally.

I have tried to curl Heketi node from a gluster-client pod and it works correctly:

```
kubectl exec -it gluster-client-6fqmb -- curl http://[myheketinodeip]:8080/hello
Hello from Heketi
```

Comment: Could you provide your YAMLs config? When you are specify storageClassName in configuration, make sure you have storageClass with the same name.

Comment: I cannot find any storageClass related to GlusterFS without Heketi provisioning. However my GlusterFS cluster is deployed on GCE and I have not any Heketi service deployed. I have edited the post with my YAMLs config. Thank you.

Comment: As I have checked it is not possible to use ReadWriteMany volumes with the standard storage class, so I need to deploy Heketi in order to be able to mount GlusterFS volumes. So I am going to deploy Heketi on my GlusterFS cluster to solve the issue.

Comment: Ok. If deploying Heketi will resolve this issue, please post this solution with description as answer. If you will encounter further issues also let me know.

Comment: @PjoterS I have a new issue related. Could you help me please?

Comment: According to SO rules, each question for 1 problem. As you were able to mount glusterfs on GKE you should write answer how you achieve that and in another question further issues.